# Display:none в адаптивной верстке

Tags: html, css, адаптивная-верстка, display

Всем привет!
Работаю над своим первым адаптивом, многих нюансов пока не знаю.

Вопрос следующий: насколько целесообразно использовать свойство display со значением none? 
Для примера: шапки для экранов шириной 320px и 1024px абсолютно разные. Я сделал 2 header-блока с соответствующей разметкой и стилями: по умолчанию шапка для 320px скрыта с помощью display:none и отображается только при соответствующем медиазапросе (а шапка для 1024px, соответственно, скрывается тем же свойством).

Так вообще делается или нужно идти другими путями?

Знаю, что можно использовать для этих целей JS, но вопрос актуален.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно, если что-то кардинально отличается на моб и десктопах, то это не плохой выход. Лично я так и поступаю.

Comment: Спасибо! На скорость загрузки никак не влияет?

Comment: @uncleacid Влияет. Но значительно или нет без кода сказать нельзя, но вам тут и не скажут. Не будете же вы приводить сюда весь проект. И в любом случае надо брать и измерять насколько значительно это влияние вам самим.

Answer (score 0):

То есть получается что в html разметке существует одновременно две шапки, только одна из них выключена? Вообще так не делается, так как html грузится до css и получается, что у вас подгружается целый лишний блок, а это влияет на время загрузки сайта - следовалеьно на его seo. Лучше создать в css под определенные размеры медиазапросы и ими уже выключать не нужные элементы. А не дублировать шапки.

Comment: Да, в разметке две шапки. Дизайнеру, конечно, руки оторвать нужно за такое: если не знать, что это дизайн под два разных разрешения - не поймешь. Выглядит, грубо говоря, как два разных сайта, разве что цветовая гамма одна. Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Лишняя пара килобайт погоды особо не сделают, главное не увлекаться.

Comment: Don't repeat your self